# Playwright URL Config - Environment variables for multiple apps and different base urls

Tags: automated-tests, playwright, base-url

**What would be the best way to configure and use urls for a project with**

- 2x WebApps
- 3x Environments

**... where we have a situation that looks like this as an example**

Fruit App

- baseurls:

  - dev.fruits.com
  - test.fruits.com
  - prod.fruits.com
- endpoints:

  - /banana/
  - /kiwi/
  - /apple/

Color App

- baseurls:

  - dev.colors.com
  - test.colors.com
  - prod.colors.com
- endpoints:

  - /red/
  - /blue/
  - /green/

**... and tests like this**

```js
    test('Navigate to fruits/banana', async () => {
      await page.goto('https://https://dev.fruits.com/banana/');
      ...
    });
     
    test('Navigate to colors/red', async () => {
      await page.goto('https://https://dev.colors.com/red/');
      ...
    });
```

**... where I'd like to**

1. Replace dev.fruits.com and dev.colors.com with baseurl variables
2. The "dev" part should be dynamic based on which environment I run tests in

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use separate [projects](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-advanced#projects) for different configurations:

```js
// @ts-check
const { devices } = require('@playwright/test');

/**
 * @see https://playwright.dev/docs/test-configuration
 * @type{import('@playwright/test').PlaywrightTestConfig}
 */
const config = {
  projects: [
    {
      name: 'Fruit Dev',
      testMatch: 'fruits/**/*',
      use: {
        baseURL: 'https://dev.fruits.com'
      }
    },
    {
      name: 'Fruit Test',
      testMatch: 'fruits/**/*',
      use: {
        baseURL: 'https://test.fruits.com'
      }
    },
    {
      name: 'Fruit Prod',
      testMatch: 'fruits/**/*',
      use: {
        baseURL: 'https://test.fruits.com'
      }
    },
    {
      name: 'Color Dev',
      testMatch: 'colors/**/*',
      use: {
        baseURL: 'https://dev.colors.com'
      }
    },
    {
      name: 'Color Test',
      testMatch: 'colors/**/*',
      use: {
        baseURL: 'https://test.colors.com'
      }
    },
    {
      name: 'Color Prod',
      testMatch: 'colors/**/*',
      use: {
        baseURL: 'https://test.colors.com'
      }
    },
  ]
};
module.exports = config;
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Would you say this way is preferred or more beneficial over using process.env variables?

Answer (score 4):

I came across this issue recently and as an alternative on using projects, I used env config files (like `dotenv`) as most of our codebase uses the same. In this instance, I categorised it based on the test environments and not on the apps used.

I created a `config` folder with the sample json files:
`config/dev.env.json`
`config/test.env.json`
`config/prod.env.json`

with the following content:

```json
{
  "fruitApp": {
    "baseUrl": "prod.fruits.com",
    "endpoints": {
      "banana": "/banana/",
      "kiwi": "/kiwi/",
      "apple": "/apple/"
    }
  },
  "colorApp": {
    "baseUrl": "prod.colors.com",
    "endpoints": {
      "banana": "/red/",
      "kiwi": "/blue/",
      "apple": "/green/"
    }
  }
}
```

Then on `playwright.config.ts`, I have the following snippet:

```js
const config = process.env.ENV || 'prod';
const env = require(`./config/${config}.env.json`); // load env from json

export default defineConfig({
  ...env,
```

On your spec/test file, you can call the above using:

```js
console.log(env.fruitApp.baseUrl)
```

---

Running your tests with:

```bash
ENV=prod npx playwright test
```

Comment: Hi ! Your solution seems to be good but i have the error : `env is not defined` in my spec/test file ! Do you know why please ?